# Shall we use noexcept everywhere in this case?

Tags: c++11, error-handling, error-code, noexcept

I am working on a project which uses error codes, and exception handling is not allowed (we are using the nothrowing version of the `new` operator).
Does it make sense to use the `noexcept` specifier on **every** function?
Which are the possible pro and cons?

Comment: I do not see any benefit. If everything is "the same" then there is no point to explicitly mark that property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it could be useful in your setup. The reason is that standard library containers and algorithms can use more optimised implementations of certain operations if these operations are `noexcept()`.

Comment: But are those optimizations worth the effort? I believe that all the defaulted constructors and assignment operators are not 'noexcept' and therefore must be manually defined... all of them...

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 - I have chosen to do this for a specific project with similar requirements.  I believe that you will see a change in the C++ language in the future that will make this much easier.

Comment: @Jeff do you mean in C++17? Or further?

Answer (score 4):

1.) I don't think it is worth it to do it on functions that are not special member functions. Special member functions are the only place that you will see a performance gain in the standard library from a `noexcept` declaration, afaik. (Possibly `swap` also?)

2.) You *can* use default declarations and `noexcept` at the same time, and you should rather than write out what would be defaulted! In a declaration like

`my_class(const my_class&) noexcept = default;`

This will cause the compiler to generate a default copy ctor and give it a noexcept declaration, even if the default copy ctor is forced to call a function that is not marked noexcept.
   In many cases, the compiler-generated special member functions are properly noexcept -- as long as they don't call something that is `noexcept(false)`. So you may not even have to mark that many functions, in order to get the majority of the benefit, if you mark most of your low-level classes this way.

An example is, in `C++11`, `std::string` move ctor is not declared `noexcept`, even though it *should be*. It's not required by the standard until C++14. I believe that this was just an oversight -- I'm not aware of any implementation where `std::string` move ctor is actually throwing, nor can I imagine why it would.

But as a result, default move constructors of classes that contain `std::string` members do not acquire a `noexcept` specification, since they are forced to call a function that may throw. So, classes that contain `std::string` data members are often a great place to use `my_class(my_class &&) noexcept = default` in C++11, IMO.

3.) `noexcept` also has value because it helps to document the code. For instance, if you are making a library I would consider putting noexcept on API functions when applicable and you don't think you will make it throw later. But putting noexcept on functions which are just internal implementation details and not special member functions, isn't likely to add that much value, imo, although it can't hurt.